# Clean index for opensemanticsearch

Tags: python, semantics, opensemanticsearch

I add few sites to test scrappy crawler and now I would like to remove them and clean up all indexed data.
In the official documentation there is command to [clean index provided](https://www.opensemanticsearch.org/doc/admin/cmd):

`opensemanticsearch-delete --empty`

But I'm not able to execute/find it.

*Note: My environment is docker containers deployed. My best guess is that this command should be available at interactive console to **open-semantic-search_etl_1**, but I'm getting "opensemanticsearch-delete: command not found" error*

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to find the script that implements this logic. You can perform it with following script:

`python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/opensemanticetl/etl_delete.py --empty`

And then confirm your intention by typing `yes` when prompted.

As for me I haven't see result (all indexed pages was accessible to search) **until I restart all containers**.

After that index was cleared and I able to start indexing from the scratch.

Comment: Is weird, In my case it works without restarting the containers.